# How to Design an Octagonal Cabin

Tags: framing, roof, construction

I asked this one earlier but it was closed for some reason, even though I was NOT asking for a product or service recommendation, but creative solutions.

I wanted ideas for building an octagonal cabin based on an existing platform/deck. So, after some research here are my plans - I hope they may be useful to someone at some point, please feel free to us them!

The framing are made of 2x4s, the platform and roof of 2x6s, the walls 1x6s and the posts are pressure-treated 4x4s. The only element I did not include are sheets of plywood, or more boards, to go between the rafters and the shingles.

[image: Uprights]
[image: Roof]
[image: Walls]
[image: Platform]

Comment: Your research should come first, then your questions about particulars. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. We're not a discussion forum, so open-ended posts like this aren't a good fit. You might give the [help pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) a glance for a better understanding of what makes a good question.

Comment: Jessie, I edited the info into your question so you can delete the  info that is in this ANSWER box below. *Please take the tour*  diy.stackexchange.com/tour   Good job rewording your "question" so it is not considered a shopping question. **Now what is the specific question you have about the design you have posted ?**

Comment: Your pictures show vertical orientation of the wall sheathing. That will not be compatible with the 1x6 boards that you said will be on the walls unless you put at least three if not four sets of blocking between all the studs. Otherwise you should plan on showing the wall sheathing boards being placed horizontal at right angles to the studs.

Comment: My main questions is is this a sound design and are there any improvements anyone could suggest? Next, how would you recommend attaching the roof to the walls - hurricane strips? I also considered horizontal overlapping siding but then it seemed it would be harder to close up the corners - is there a way to use this type of siding without having gaps at the corners?